# Does using nonce or sha-256 allow executing inline event handlers?

Tags: express, content-security-policy, helmet.js

i have a little doubt about content security policy...my rendering file pug consists of inline event handlers like `onclick='someFunction()'` ...after i installed helmet for adding extra headers it is blocking my inline event handlers for violating csp..after some research i came to know that to allow inline scripts we have to use either unasafe-inline, nonce or hash..so i putted nonce in my script tags in the pug file like `script(src="source", nonce='123456')` and in helmet middleware set the content-security-policies script-src to 'nonce-123456'..but still i cant execute inline event handlers..my question is using nonce or sha-256 just allow the linline scripts like`<script nonce='123456'> someFunction() </script>` to work or it will allow both inline script and inline event handlers to execute??..i know that instead of inline event handlers i can use addEventListener()..but there is any way to use inline event handlers??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It only allows the script element to be executed.

An `onclick` attribute would be a different source.

`‘unsafe-inline'` will allow inline event handler attributes but would be highly vulnerable to XSS without the possibility of mitigating with a nonce.

Use `addEventListener`.

Answer (score 0):

When working with Content Security Policy (CSP), you can use the `nonce` attribute in combination with `addEventListener` to create secure event handlers. This allows you to execute inline scripts while maintaining a strong security posture.

For an illustrative example, you can visit the following link: https://csplite.com/csp155/.